# Type 'Observable<client[]>' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<!--client component.html-->
  <div *ngFor="let client of clientss">
  <h3>{{client.name}}</h3>
  </div>
```

```
/***client services****/
getclients() {
  return this.http.get<client[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
}
```

```
    //client.component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { ClientsServicesService } from 'src/app/services/clients-services.service';
    import { client } from './client';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-api-clints',
      templateUrl: './api-clints.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./api-clints.component.css']
    })
    export class ApiClintsComponent implements OnInit {
      clientsApi:any=[]
    
      clientss!:Observable<client[]>;
    
      constructor(private clientervicss:ClientsServicesService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.clientss = this.clientervicss.getclients();
    }
    }
```

```
    **//client interface**
    export interface client {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      email: string;
    }
```

am trying to run the code above but getting error
Type 'Observable<client[]>' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.
22 <div *ngFor="let client of clientss">
~~

src/app/components/api-clints/api-clints.component.ts:8:16
8   templateUrl: './api-clints.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ApiClintsComponent.

Comment: I think you should use async pipe in your .html to get data.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning clients to observable, you must subscribe it;

```
this.clientervicss.getclients().subscribe(clients => {
this.clientss = clients;
});
```

Comment: also have to change `clientss` type then ;)

Comment: just use async pipe as Mateusz pointed out.

Comment: @ABOS both are valid. Depends what OP wishes to do with his clientss.

Comment: @Random, I am not saying the answer is wrong - for the simple case like OP encountered, async is enough, unless OP needs more complex use cases.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. I used the pipe and the problem was solved. I am very happy to benefit from your experiences

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
  <div *ngFor="let client of (clientss | async)">
    <h3>{{client.name}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Explanation:

clients is an observable, you have to subscribe to it, to get it's value, which is an `ngIterable | null | undefined` and which is accepted by `ngFor`

Note:
The module where you `client.component` is MUST have in it's `imports` `CommonModule` OR a module that imports it.

Comment: Typo 'clientss' -> 'clients'. Also the module with client.component mustn't necessarily have CommonModule as an import. What if it's in the AppModule? Or a library? That whole last sentence is entirely irrelevant to the question, really.

Comment: DO you know for a fact that AppModule exists in his project? have I referred to any AppModule? mustn't a component be in a module? mustn't that module import CommonModule or a module that imports CommonModule for the async pipe to work ?
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Your tone is one of one at the summit of a Dunning-Kruger curve

Comment: Lol, pot/kettle, eh? ;) But given that the OP says they ran the project and got an error, I'm rather certain they have a main (App) module.

Comment: I would rather mention that commonModule is necessary for asyncPipe to work than to assume they have imported it ( an acceptable feedback would have been, that in the imports we must have EITHER CommonModule OR a module that imports it )